# Can't create a new notebook on Jupiter from a instantiation launched from google cloud console

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

Trying to create a new Jupiter notebook, selecting `new > Python3`  from google cloud console I am getting the following error message:

[image]

The logs show this:

```
[W 09:08:59.601 NotebookApp] Blocking Cross Origin API request for /api/contents.  Origin: https://8888-cs-401007120000-default.cs-europe-west1-akef.cloudshell.dev, Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
[W 09:08:59.601 NotebookApp] Not Found
[W 09:08:59.602 NotebookApp] 404 POST /api/contents (127.0.0.1) 2.090000ms referer=https://8888-cs-401007120000-default.cs-europe-west1-akef.cloudshell.dev/tree?authuser=1
```

So I launch Jupiter notebooks with the following command to solve the issue:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'
```

But after accessing the notebooks they appear as "not connected".

[image]

The logs are showing:

```
[W 10:53:06.829 NotebookApp] Couldn't authenticate WebSocket connection
[W 10:53:06.831 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/kernels/80b0000e-8a1e-405e-9d3c-fe3000720038/channels?session_id=0b000ff004ed4fd000aa0eabdaf0e00d (127.0.0.1) 3.390000ms referer=None
```

I found several issues in GitHub with a similar problem in which is advised trying out to launching the notebooks with a different explorer. It did not work for me in either Chrome, Safari or Firefox.

Comment: From the title I am not sure if you are talking about a VM instantiation or an AI Platform Notebook instantiation. Are you using an AI Platform Notebook or a Notebook that you have installed on your own in a VM. If it is the latter, are you using a version older then 4.3.0? Because I wonder if the [bug fixes](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html?highlight=corss%20origin#release-4-3) at this version could be related.

Comment: I've installed it on google cloud, directly from the console provided in the big query environment

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding here. Because there isn't any option to create a notebook from the BigQuery page in the Console. You can either install Jupyter directly in a VM created from your Console's GCE page or from the Console's AI Platform pages. You will need to be more specific or to point to a related documentation that you have maybe followed.